# How to get data between 2 dates in sql lite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get date from date base in the range of two dates via using below query

`SELECT * FROM TransactionLog WHERE TransactionDate > '2016-04-04'`

It is fetching data correctly but when I am including time along with date then it is not fetching data

`SELECT * FROM TransactionLog WHERE TransactionDate > '2016-04-04 11:17:07'`

This is the query i am using for date and time.
Is there a different way when time is included?

Comment: [Google said](https://www.google.co.in/#q=How+to+get+data+between+2+dates+in+sqlite+android?)

Comment: Show some example records that you think should match.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM "your table" WHERE date BETWEEN "from date" AND "to date";
```

and also remember that "`from date`" and "`to date`" are dates not string. First convert your strings to date and then compare.

Comment: It is working but when i include time along with dates then it does not work for me this way

Comment: SQLite has no "date" data type; these values indeed are strings.

Comment: BETWEEN '2011-11-08 00:00:00' AND '2011-11-10 00:00:00'

Comment: select * 
  from MyTable 
  where mydate >= Datetime('2000-01-01 00:00:00') 
  and mydate <= Datetime('2050-01-01 23:00:59')

Comment: What's wrong with this query ? SELECT * FROM transactionList WHERE transactionDate BETWEEN  '2018-05-28  ' AND  '2018-04-28 ' LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0.plz help